Is Bridge Mode on Docker the same thing as NAT Network on VirtualBox?
For me they're the same. There's the host that handles the IP's to the virtual machines and they can communicate with each other and with the host, but not see other devices on the Local Network.
Another question: my host.docker.internal has an IP of 192.168.0.100, but, when I'm inside a container, there's an IP that I can ping that is 172.17.0.1, what is this and how this works?

but not see other devices on the Local Network That doesn't really have anything to do with NAT (in the general sense), but the fact that the VMs (or containers in the docker case) are in a separate broadcast domain. And while therefore in the sense of "discovery" they cannot "see" devices in the host LAN (because that usually leverages IP multicast), it doesn't mean that they cannot "reach" them through unicast, like how they reach an Internet host).

If your doubt is really whether bridge networking in docker is different from bridged networking in VirtualBox or alike, and/or how they are different: the latter means that the VMs are bridged to an existing (usually physical) network, i.e., they are made to "join" an existing broadcast domain, whereas "bridge" (with no d) in "bridge networking" refers only to the fact that a (Linux) bridge (which is like a virtual switch) is used interconnect the containers (i.e., no physical / existing interface is enslaved to the bridge to make them bridged to an existing network).

@TomYan , much thanks friend, I'm really grateful! The difference of bridge and bridged was confusing my mind for a long time, good to see people like you helping people like me ahahahah

They're different in several ways.

VirtualBox 'NAT' mode implements routing (and bridging between VMs) entirely inside VirtualBox – the internal network is invisible even to the host, which only sees VirtualBox.exe as the one making network connections.
Docker 'bridge' mode instead relies on the host OS for bridging between containers and for routing between docker0 and the world – the bridge is visible to the host as a virtual network interface and traffic can automatically go in, not only out, without having to configure 'port forward' rules upfront. It is much more similar to the VirtualBox 'Host-Only' mode (which is host-only only in name).

Because of 1), the VirtualBox 'NAT' mode is strictly limited to VirtualBox VMs, while a Linux "bridge" interface can also have almost any other Ethernet-type interface as a member. For example, it's possible to put a QEMU VM's 'tap' interface in the same bridge – and it's even possible to put physical interfaces in the same bridge, giving similar results to VirtualBox 'bridged' mode.



It is much more similar to the VirtualBox 'Host-Only' mode (which is host-only only in name). To be fair though, NAT is not set up automatically on the host side for traffics from a host-only network, and the DHCP server does not advertise a default gateway to the VMs (no DNS server either, IIRC). With respect to these, I think one can say it is much more similar to NAT (service/network) in VBox too...
